# How to determine the patch file name through InstallShield patchDesign view

Tags: installshield, patch

Usage of InstallShield 2018 patchdesign view to create patch files (`.msp`):
I have some questions regarding this view:

1. Where and how can I specify the .msp file name? is it possible to be set by environment variable value that I pass to InstallShild by the `-l` flag?
2. can you please tell if `ISLatestRelease` can be declared as environment variable and passed to installshield with `-l` ISCMDBld.exe flag?
3. can "previous setup path" be declared by environment variable and passed to installshield with `-l` ISCMDBld.exe flag, I'm trying to avoid hardcoded path?
4. does Identification tab can contain environment variable?
   Thank you!
   Donna

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to automate using environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installshield generates patches(.msp) with "Patch package.msp" name. You can rename it using any scripting once Iscmdbld.exe generates the msp file.

Use the IswiAuto19.ISWiProject automation interface for automation.
https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm